# Distributing iOS applications for BYOD users

Tags: ios, enterprise-distribution

I am developing an iOS application for an organisation that allows its users to BYOD.

I'm unclear as exactly how the Apple Enterprise Developer Programme works. Is there an additional app store installed onto user's devices? Does the organisation have to somehow register the user's device as part of the Enterprise Developer Programme?

The app is intended for internal use and so don't really want to make it available on the public app store. Would Apple's Volume Purchasing Programme be more suitable than the Enterprise programme?

Comment: Enterprise apps can be loaded onto any device from a web site, such as the company intranet.  The user will get a prompt that they have to trust the developer (the enterprise) when they install the app. Many MDM vendors make this process simpler and i would strongly suggest the organisation uses an MDM to manage even BYO devices. VPP makes it possible for an app developer to make custom versions of an app available to a VPP customer. The VPP customer still needs to distribute the app to its users, again through an MDM

Comment: I think TestFlight can be used to distribute app keeping the App not open to world, an app can easily be shared with email invitation within organisation through iTunes Store, but that requires the TestFlight app to be installed in the Device and read [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingApplicationsOutside/DistributingApplicationsOutside.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH12-SW2) and [this](https://longtrieuquang.wordpress.com/2014/08/01/how-to-distribute-your-ios-app-ota-with-enterprise-account/)